# Join RTP streams in java

Tags: java, rtp

I'm implementing conference voip in java.
In practice, each client (softtone sip implemented by me) receives RTP audio streams coming from different sources (in any case the same sampling 8000Hz 20 ms) and must merge them and then be sent to the playback device (eg speakers).
In java there is no possibility to open more than one audio stream on the same device (at least that's what I have read, understood and even experienced personally). Consequently, as I have read on various forums including Stackoverflow itself, it is necessary to merge the rtp streams by buffering the sampling blocks (in my case 160 kb) and then merge them together, when they collide as a timestamp.
Given that the implementation of the buffering and the merging of 2 RTP buffers that collide as timestamps are implemented, what still does not work for me is the synchronization, or how to calculate the right timeslot for each RTP coming from 2 or more sources.
After countless failures (bad or degraded sound) and several readings on the forums, articles and thesis I realized that the timestamp must be unique and therefore the RTCP protocol must be used which sends the NTP timestamp which is (clearly) common to all sources at stake. Despite this it still doesn't work so I went ahead with my studies and found another source an article by CISCO

[https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=705533&seqNum=6](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

which argues that the sources must be correlated with each other (I have interpreted that all sources must be re-adapted to a single appropriately chosen time flow, applying the following formulas:

(1) RTP_B = RTP_A / (audio sample rate) + AtoV

This equation converts the RTP_B of the time base of the local audio device into units of seconds by dividing the timestamp of the audio device by the sample rate of the audio. The receiver determines the AtoV offset by simultaneously observing RTP_A_time, the RTP_B real-time clock value, and RTP_A_time, the real-time audio device clock value. Therefore

(2) AtoV = RTP_B_time - RTP_A_Time / (audio sample rate)

So the steps I thought:

1. I choose the RTCP timestamp that comes first.
2. Atov calculation with formula (2)
3. with formula (1) I readjust each RTP packet to the time flow chosen in step 1 and calculate the slot
4. I buffer the packet in the slot calculated in point 3, merging it in the event of a collision.

All this lacks the jitter calculated as:

J (i) = J (i-1) + ((| D ((i-1), i) | -J (i-1)) / 16

where D = packets sent - packets received
| D ((i-1), i) | = | D (i-1) - D (i) |

can I add it after the hiccup in point 3) increasing the slot of the jitter value or do I always have to reapply the formula (1) to readjust it to the reference time stream?

Are the steps right?
am I doing something wrong?
is there something ready on the net?

thanks everyone in advance for the help
Maximilian

Are the steps right?
am I doing something wrong?
is there something ready on the net?